# Change annotation(Evaluate=true/false ) for parameters in models from Modelica Standard Library

Tags: modelica

I am using some components from the Modelica Standard Library (MSL) in my simulations. These components each have some parameters. For example, `Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T`  has a `parameter m_flow`. Usually, parameters can be changed between simulation runs without re-compilation. This is not the case for `m_flow`, because it has an `annotation(Evaluate=true)`, so it is used for symbolic processing.
Is it possible to change the annotations of parameters at instantiation? I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T source2(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium2,
    nPorts=1,
    m_flow=22.17 annotation(Evaluate=false));
```

Of course there are workarounds, like making a copy first and changing the annotation there or using `use_m_flow_in=true` and a constant source block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible with current Modelica Specification.
Some tools might support it if you extend MassFlowSource_T:

```
model MassFlowSource_T_2
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T;
  // declare m_flow here again with annotation(Evaluate=false);
end MassFlowSource_T_2;

use MassFlowSource_T_2 when you declare source2.
```

There is some work in progress to extend the way annotations are specified/handled 
but it will be a while until it makes it into the Modelica Specification:
https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/1293 (not open to the public yet).

Comment: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/1293 migrated, but still not open to the public