# Parameters Sometimes Not Editable in Dymola Simulation Tab and FMU

Tags: modelica, dymola

Example:

You create a model with 9 parameters you expect to be editable in the Simulation tab and user-settable in the FMU.

However,

1. Only 5 parameters appear to be editable from the Simulation tab.
2. Likewise, FMU has only 5 user-settable parameters.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32739428/874701

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

To generate more efficient code, Dymola sometimes "evaluates" parameters.

`annotation(Evaluate=false)` tells Dymola a parameter should not be evaluated.

Example:

```
parameter Real theAnswer = 42.0 "The answer to life,…" annotation(Evaluate=false);
```

Dymola will now allow `theAnswer` to be edited in the Simulation tab and be user-settable in the FMU.